# Loading .NetCore DLL's in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core

I've created some .DLL's compiled using .NetCore 1.1. I now need to load them into Powershell and call their methods. Is this supported or do my DLL's need to be compiled using the full version of .Net?

Comment: PowerShell is based on the .NET Framework, not .NET Core. If you build your assembly against the appropriate [`netstandard` profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) (and its dependencies are also deployed), it should run on .NET Framework. If you build it explicitly as .NET Core only, it might not.

Answer (score 4):

Your .NET Core dlls won't run on standard out of the box windows only flavored powershell.

But! There is a .NET Core friendly version of powershell here: [Powershell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

Powershell Core will run on Windows, Linux, and macOS, just as .NET Core was meant to run.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when trying to do something similar. I succeeded in loading a .NET Core dll in the following way:

```
// You can use namespaces, but also paths
using assembly 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.4\System.Text.Json.dll'

// Specific for the static method I use in my example
$options = New-Object System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions

// Use the Serialize method of the static class JsonSerializer
$jsonString = [System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer]::Serialize($device, $options);
```

I used System.Text.Json, but you can do this with any dll.

Source:
[Powershell 7 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 0):

To add a DLL to a powershell script use the following code: `Add-Type -Path "C:\locationOfDLL\mydll.dll"`. See if that works for accessing the dll as needed.